# Stash auto increment project version number

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

Is there any way I could Auto Increment the Project version number (in Package.json) after the pull request from Develop to Master has been approved ?

Once the pull request is approved from Develop to Master I am looking for a way to automatically increment the version number in my projects Package.json file.

We are also using Bamboo to run our builds, I am also thinking is there a way to auto increment after the build is successful, how can we achieve this ?

Please suggest the appropriate design.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is that my CI runs `npm version patch` to update the package version. `minor, major, specific version number, ...` can also be used instead of `patch`.

By default this will also create a git tag with the version number. You can disable this with `--no-git-tag-version`.

After that you can have you CI push the created tag.

Comment: If you do from bamboo (CI) then how would you determine whether to increment, the major or minor versions?